# DataRow nulled in Foreach

Tags: c#, database, oop

I wrote a method to load data of a user from a DB. My DataRow linha is nulled so I can't read this data. Whats the correct way to read this line?

```
private void _Load(string ALogin) {
    MySqlCommand sqlQuery = new MySqlCommand($"select u.login, u.nome, u.tipo, u.ativo, m.id, m.nome, m.crm, m.habilitado FROM sis_usuarios u LEFT JOIN sis_medicos m ON u.medico = m.id WHERE u.login = \"{ALogin}\"", _dbConn.GetConnection());
    sqlQuery.Prepare();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery);
    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(tabela);

    if (tabela.Rows.Count != 1) {
        throw new Exception($"Usuário não encontrado! \nLogin: {ALogin}");
    }

    foreach(DataRow linha in tabela.Rows) {
        this.Nome = linha["nome"].ToString();
        this.Login = linha["login"].ToString();
        if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(linha)) {
            this.Medico = new MedicoModel(Int32.Parse(linha["m.id"].ToString()),
                                     linha["m.nome"].ToString(),
                                     linha["m.crm"].ToString(),
                                     Boolean.Parse(linha["m.habilitado"].ToString()));
            _Mode = Mode.EDT;
        }
    }
}
```

VisualStudio 2019 C#

Comment: You cannot test the whole row against DbNull. You need to test the individual fields. There is a [_DataRow.IsNull(fieldname)_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataRow_IsNull_System_String_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change from

```
if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(linha)) {
```

to

```
if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(linha["nome"])) {
```

because as Steve mentioned in the comments, DBNull.Value should be used with column values not rows

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test the whole row against DbNull. You need to test the individual fields, or, at least in this context, at least the ID field.

There is a [DataRow.IsNull(fieldname)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataRow_IsNull_System_String_)

```
if(!linha.IsNull("id")) {
    this.Medico = new MedicoModel(Int32.Parse(linha["id"].ToString()),
                             linha["nome"].ToString(),
                             linha["crm"].ToString(),
                             Boolean.Parse(linha["habilitado"].ToString()));
```

Notice that you don't need the alias prefix once the data is into the datatable rows.

Said that, there is another serious problem in your query. You are concatenating string to create an sql command. This is a well known problem leading the Sql Injection hacks and parsing errors. You should use parameters like here:

```
MySqlCommand sqlQuery = new MySqlCommand(@"select u.login, u.nome, 
   u.tipo, u.ativo, m.id, m.nome, m.crm, m.habilitado 
   FROM sis_usuarios u LEFT JOIN sis_medicos m ON u.medico = m.id 
   WHERE u.login = @login", _dbConn.GetConnection());
sqlQuery.Parameters.Add("@login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ALogin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `linha["m.crm"]` try to use `linha["crm"]`.

`m.crm` used in the SQL statement is just part of the SQL select command executed in SQL server, and the result of this select (the dataset) contains `crm` without the table alias `m.` as the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You need change in two places. 1. change the If condition. Refer [DBNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) documentation 2. remove `m.` from field names

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(linha["id"])) 
{
    this.Medico = new MedicoModel(Int32.Parse(linha["id"].ToString()),
                               linha["nome"].ToString(),
                               linha["crm"].ToString(),                                                                                 
                               Boolean.Parse(linha["habilitado"].ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your fields on `null` and after checking you can safely create an object:

```
var id = linha["id"];
var nom = linha["nome"];
var crm = linha["crm"];
var habilitado = linha["habilitado"];

if (id != null && nom != null &&  crm != null && habilitado != null) 
{
    this.Medico = new MedicoModel((int)id, nom.ToString(), 
        crm.ToString(), (bool)habilitado); 
}
```